# Executing API requests in loop results in socket hangup

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios

I am executing API requests in a loop. Here is the code I am using to call APIs.

```
async function getTypeSuggestions(tokens: any, word_index: any): Promise<any> {
  // console.dir(tokens, {'maxArrayLength': null});
  
    const apiUrl: string = LOCALHOST_BASE_URL + PORT_NUM + "/suggest-types";
    const jsonPayload = {
      input_string: tokens,
      word_index: word_index,
    };

    return axios.post(apiUrl, jsonPayload)
}
```

This code works correctly for 1-2 iterations, after which it throws this error:

```
  cause: Error: socket hang up
      at connResetException (node:internal/errors:714:14)
      at Socket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:519:23)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:523:35)
      at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1367:12)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
    code: 'ECONNRESET'
```

But, the same API when I execute using curl exec:

```
async function getTypeSuggestions(tokens: any, word_index: any): Promise<any> {
  // console.dir(tokens, {'maxArrayLength': null});
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const apiUrl: string = LOCALHOST_BASE_URL + PORT_NUM + "/suggest-types";
    filterTokens(tokens, "'");
    const jsonPayload = JSON.stringify({
      input_string: tokens,
      word_index: word_index,
    }).replace(/"/g, '\\"');

    const curlCommand = `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw '${jsonPayload}' ${apiUrl}`;
    //console.log(curlCommand);
    exec(curlCommand, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        // console.log("Payload: ", JSON.stringify({
        //   input_string: tokens,
        //   word_index: word_index,
        // }))
        console.error("Error executing curl command:", error);
        reject(error);
      } else {
        try {
          const result = JSON.parse(stdout);
          // console.log("result from getTypeSuggesstions:", result);
          resolve(result);
        } catch (parseError) {
          console.error("Error parsing JSON response:", parseError);
          reject(parseError);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Works like a charm.

Is there any way I can rectify the code so that the axios one works? Is there something missing that I am overlooking?